# select UNION except one column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, union

i have a question:

I want to join two SQL querys into one query using UNION to avoid duplicates, but i need to know if the data comes from the fisrt select query or from the second select query.

Sample data:

```
 A TABLE                                                B TABLE
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
01 JOHN                                                01 JOHN
02 JUAN                                                02 PETER
03 MARTIN                                              03 MARTIN
```

I have something like this:

```
Select A.code,A.name from A where some conditions
unión
Select B.code,B.name from B where diferent conditions
```

RESULT TABLE

---

```
    01 JOHN                                                
    02 JUAN  
    02 PETER
    03 MARTIN
```

This Works fine, but now if i want to know if the data comes from first query or from the second i think something like this:

```
Select A.code,A.name, 'A'   from A where some conditions
unión
Select B.code,B.name, 'B'   from B where diferent conditions
```

RESULT TABLE

---

```
    01 JOHN  'A'                                              
    01 JOHN  'B'
    02 JUAN  'A'
    02 PETER 'B'
    03 MARTIN 'A'
    03 MARTIN 'B'
```

But don't avoid "duplicates" because 'A' is diferent to 'B', so the question is, can i do something so that they don't compare the 'A' with the 'B'?, is another way to obtain the expected result?

EDIT:

The expected result

---

```
    01 JOHN  'A'                                              
    02 JUAN  'A'
    02 PETER 'B'
    03 MARTIN 'A'
```

Comment: What happens when John is in both A and B? Is it ok for the query to only tell you it's in A ?

Comment: Yes, is well for me that it´s only in A, is just what i expect, I edited to see the result what i expect

Comment: Then jarlh's answer should do the trick.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's another way of doing it:

```
SELECT code, name, MIN(SourceTable) AS SourceTable
FROM (
  SELECT code, name, 'A' AS SourceTable         
  FROM A

  UNION 

  SELECT code, name, 'B' AS SourceTable         
  FROM B) t
GROUP BY code, name 
ORDER BY code
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8774d6/8)

or perhaps:

```
SELECT code, name, SourceTable
FROM (
  SELECT code, name, SourceTable,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY code, name 
                            ORDER BY SourceTable) AS rn
  FROM (
    SELECT code, name, 'A' AS SourceTable         
    FROM A

    UNION ALL

    SELECT code, name, 'B' AS SourceTable         
    FROM B) t) AS x
WHERE x.rn = 1
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8774d6/7)

Answer (score 4):

```
Select A.code, A.name, 'A' from A where some conditions
union
Select B.code, B.name, 'B' from B
where different conditions
  and not exists (select 1 from A
                  where some conditions
                    and A.code = B.code
                    and A.name = B.name)
```

Do the `UNION` as before, but don't return B rows that have already been returned from the A select.

Comment: Thanks, Works fine for me

Comment: I voted  to the @Giorgos Betsos as the correct answer because his  better performance

Comment: Anyway your answer is more easy to me  to understand why it works

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
Select A.code, A.name, 'A' col_name  from A where some conditions
UNION ALL
Select B.code, B.name, 'B'   from B where different conditions
```

Union will remove the duplicates whereas Union All will not.

**EDIT:**

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT DISTINCT A.code, A.name From A WHERE some conditions
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT B.code, B.name From B WHERE different conditions
) t
```

Comment: Isn't this the opposite of what he needs?

Comment: @MihaiOvidiuDrăgoi:- I think OP wants to keep the duplicates, thats why I suggested to do so. See this line `But don't avoid "duplicates`

Comment: I agree with Mihai Ovidiu Drăgoi - I think the question is equivalent to "how to use distinct only a part of the row?"

Comment: Thanks for answer, What i need or i expect is that in case of duplicates it keep only one of the duplicates rows, i edited to see what i expect

Comment: @Ion:- You can check jarlh answer! That will do exactly what you need